# How to run php job every 30 minutes with different value?

Tags: php, bash, shell, scripting, cron

I ask for your help because I'm literally going crazy (given that I do not have much knowledge about it, but I'm trying to understand something).

This is my big problem :

I have a `php job`. This job makes a check on DB but this is not important. The real problem is that **this job must run every 30 min from 9 AM to 00PM**. But:

1. the job must be launched with this value: `-f 'YYYY-mm-dd H:i:s' -t 'YYYY-mm-dd H:i:s'` where `-f` is the start date parameters and `-t` the end date parameters.
2. when the jobs is run is necessary to have some check that controls if the job was already running and in this case must wait.

I thought that then I need a script that writes a file with something like "OK | last time of processing" or if something was wrong "KO | last time of succesfull elaboration".

So a crontab I must have a line like this: `*/30 9-23 * * * /path/script >/dev/null 2>&1`

Then:

1. the script must call the php function: `cd /data/httpd/magento && /opt/rh/php54/root/usr/bin/php /data/httpd/magento/job.php`
2. must launch the `job.php` with `-f 'date -u "+%F %H:%M:%S"' -t 'date -u "+%F %H:%M:%S"'` with a range of **30 minutes**.

Example: script start at 9 AM so the range date value is `-f '2018-08-07 07:00:00' -t '2018-08-07 07:30:00'` and write in the log file something like "Elaboration OK | 2018-08-07 07:30:00")

3. after 30 min the script run agains. Before running, it reads the log file and in particular the last processing in OK status and put the corret date range value for the run of php job.

I hope I was clear. Maybe it's bullshit but it's driving me crazy

Comment: It seems to me it would be simpler to create the PHP to do all those checks and balances. Using a simple table to record the last good run. And making all those date parameters calculate dynamically on each execution. You can stop the job running at the same time as another, using a simple file lock check

Comment: I see two possibilities.  Like @RiggsFolly commented, get your PHP script to figure it out on its own and call it every 30 minutes.  Or if you cannot modify it, create a bash script to wrap it and call that bash script in cron.  The bash script will need to calculate the parameters, form the log file.  http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/